# Paypal Pre-aapproved Payments with Laravel and handle recuring payments later

Tags: laravel, paypal, recurring

**My Scenario**

I am trying to allow user to add paypal payment methods on my webiste (in Laravel) so later he can use the added payment methods to make payment.

right now i am using the https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal to handle the recurring payment methods but now we want user to add multiple paypal payment methods so when he want to purchase the subscription then he can be able to select the added payment method.

**My Question**

Is there a package or method for use with laravel that allows me to implement pre-approved payments and handle the recurring payment methods later?

Answer (score 0):

Guarv, thanks for using my package. Pre-approved payments are part of PayPal AdaptivePayments API. My package supports it partially though. Hopefully we can work together to implement this in the package.

If you look at this link:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/

It specifically says if you are using pre-approved payments, you should use the Adaptive Payments endpoint to process any future payments.

Comment: Raza, as we using your package we able to handle the recurring payments and its working fine, but is there any way in your package that we CreateBillingAgreement while first time payment and after that in case of subscription upgrade we can make payment from that paypal account with which we created the billing agreement, rather than to go to paypal again?

Comment: One way to do is that you either create a billing agreement & then you perform reference transactions based on that billing agreement.

Comment: Raza, as we were creating the recurring payment profile before to handle the future payments. But now we creating the billing agreement first then we trying to create the recurring payment but it while creating recurring payment we getting the error in response "A successful Billing Agreement has already been created for this token"

So we are little confuse here that we need to use the recurring profile and billing agreement together or not?

if we not create the recurring profile then we need to handle the future payments by cron on meet the subscription end date? right?
Please assist.